# L-tree Framework Mesh generation

Tags: 3d, geometry, graph-algorithm, mesh, point

So here is my problem. I have generated a 3D Framwork from the Lindenmayer algorithm and now i want to generate a 3D Triangle-Mesh for it. is there any good way(algorithm) for generating the Mesh?

I need for a University Projekt.

edit:

I am generating a L-Word, then building a frame made of lines for each letter a line in a 3-Dimensional room. after that i want to surround the lines with a Mesh.

Comment: What kind of data do you have that you want to transform into a mesh?

Comment: it is a list of verticies and edges, built from the L-Tree algorithm

Comment: I assume, the vertices you have are in 2D? How do you want the 3D mesh to look like?

Comment: No the meshes are in 3D

Comment: Maybe, it has not become clear enough, so let me try to be more explicit: It is very unclear what problem you are trying to solve. The question is lacking information about how the input data looks like and what kind of output you expect. Those are the minimum requirements for a question to be answerable. Please add this information to the question. Also, consult [ask]. Adding images of examples may help a lot.

Comment: let me try to do it here again, i am generating a 3D frame(just like drawing a stick figure) from the L-System and now i want to suround the frame with a Mesh so it looks like a tree.